# How to use the set intersection method in python

Tags: python, intersection

```
at_set = {'Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3'}
for files in os.listdir(zipped_trots_files):
    zipped_path = os.path.join(zipped_trots_files, files)
    with open(zipped_path, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in reader:
            read = [row for row in reader if row] 
            for row in read:
                if set(row).intersection(at_set):
                    print(row)
```

I guess i'm using the intersection function wrong...can someone see it? I'm trying to print only the rows who contain either `Num1`, `Num2` or `Num3`

When I do `print` I receive nothing...

Comment: I think there are too many iteration constructs there. `for row in reader` already iterates over rows, then `[row for row in reader if row]` does it again, then `for row in read:` actually iterates over individual cells but the iterator variable is again called `row`... and `set(row)` probably creates the set of characters inside a single cell.

Comment: @Thomas, actually in first iteration then it completes iterating over csv.reader inside the list comprehension. I.e. I think it makes just iteration in the outside for loop

Comment: @buran Yes, but my comment was already long enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are duplicated iterations. You need to remove the excessive iterations or go back to the beginning of `reader` by calling `output.seek(0)`.

```py
at_set = {'Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3'}
for files in os.listdir(zipped_trots_files):
    zipped_path = os.path.join(zipped_trots_files, files)
    with open(zipped_path, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in reader:
            if row and set(row).intersection(at_set):
                print(row)
```

Comment: Looks proper but still receiving an empty response...

Comment: how about posting your sample file here?

Comment: Fixed it already Thank you bro. The delimiter was comma seperated and not tab seperated.